# XDocument how to save without Byte Order Mark AND preseve formatting/whitespace

Tags: c#

I am able to remove the Byte Order Mark using this code:

```
using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(file, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
{
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.None;
    xdoc.Save(writer);
}
```

The problem with this though is that my formatting becomes messed up and all the whitespace is removed. For example:

```
<root>
  <data name="A" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>A</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

Now becomes:

```
<root><data name="A" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>A</value>
</data></root>
```

Is there any way to remove this byte order mark and keep the original formatting of the file?

Comment: Why are you setting `writer.Formatting = Formatting.None;`? Try setting `writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;` instead or don't set it at all.

Comment: I'm such an idiot.. this literally solved my problem that I spent ages trying to fix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved (Updated due to issue with creating unnecessary whitespace):

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(file, settings))
{
     xdoc.Save(writer);
}
```