# Save XDocument without any formatting changes

Tags: c#, xml, format, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have a XML File where i have to replace a single value of an element. For this im loading my XML file into a `XDocument`: `var camtXml = XDocument.Load(fileStream);` After im done with my changes and saving the XDocument to a file there are multiple changes that shouldn't be done. As you can see in the following picture (Left side file from XDocument, rigth site original file):
[image]

The UTF-8 was changed from upper- to lower case, CR Linefeeds were added and
the indentation has been changed by removing withespaces. I really wan't to use XDocument because of its libary what easily allows to create and iterate through XElements. But the formatting changes are a show stopper. Is there a way to preserve these formatting changes or is there an alternativ to XDocument with the same options like XPath, XElement etc.?
I found this but it didn't solved my problem.
[XDocument how to save without Byte Order Mark AND preseve formatting/whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56898435/xdocument-how-to-save-without-byte-order-mark-and-preseve-formatting-whitespace)

Comment: XDocument doesn't preserve the original format because it parses the xml to a in memory representation of its nodes. When you save, it recreates the string from its model. How are you generating the output? Because if I'm not mistaken, you can choose the new line char to be `\r\n`

Comment: Also, why do you need to keep the whitespace as it is?

Comment: Any xml reader will parse the modified code so I so not know what your concerns are.  It should not be a show stopper.

Comment: @jdweng Im only changing one vlaue of an element. For this project it is a show stopper because in the comparision should only the one change show up and not like now x changes.

Comment: @Magnetron Im saving the XDocument via a FileStream first but now with an XML-Writer. But it sounds like there is no way to do it with XDocument right? But if so, is there any alternativ?

Comment: @Max yeah, just tested and XDocument don't respect the TextWriter NewLine. One alternative is to generate the string and replace afterwards, but I don't think you will find a library that does what you want.

Comment: So uses Beyond Compare to see changes and ignore white spaces and upper/lower case.

Comment: @Magnetron I think im loading the file to an string and working with regex then. Just thought there will be a solution for my problem cause i really like to work with the XML libarys from .NET

Comment: @jdweng to change the comparison is no option and was not the question. The comparision is not done by my side or system.

Comment: What are the requirements?  Your comparison has to meet the requirements.  if the XML doesn't change, the XML specification doesn't care about white spaces nor the case of the Indent line.

Comment: @Magnetron: When you *need* to change hand-generated and hand-indented XML without messing up the hand formatting you will understand.